# Upgrade gnu make on mac

Tags: macos, makefile, macos-sierra

I am trying to upgrade gnu make version to 4.1 on my mac, but I couldn't install successfully. Here are what I did so far:
1. install xcode v8.2.1
2. manually upgrade gnu make with the following commands.

```
# Download gnu make-4.1.tar.gz from gnu website.
./configure
make 
sudo make install
```

This doesn't make my `make` version to v4.1 when I type `make --version` on my terminal.
3. Running `xcode-select --install` on command line didn't solve the problem either.

My system info:

```
$ sw_vers -productVersion
$ v10.12.4
$ cmake --version
$ v3.10.0
$ make --version
$ 3.81
```

Thanks.

Comment: Consider using **homebrew** from https://brew.sh IMHO it is a superb package manager for **macOS**. Then your command would simply be `brew install make`

Comment: @MarkSetchell: I've already instal homebrew and run `brew install make` . byw, running `brew upgrade make` shows `Error: make 4.2.1_1 already installed`.

Comment: You can try with command `gmake` instead of make
`gmake --version` is `make` version 4.2.1_1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put the path where make install installs before the path where the old make is found it will use the newer make.

If the old one lives in `/opt/xcode/bin` and make install installs to `/usr/local/bin`, then make sure `/usr/local/bin` comes before `/opt/xcode/bin` in your PATH variable.

> PATH=/usr/local/bin:/opt/xcode/bin

Comment: It shows `v3.81` when I run `/usr/bin/make --version`. Running `/usr/local/bin/make --version`, it shows 'make v4.1'. By running `echo $PATH`, `/usr/local/bin/make` already comes before `/usr/bin/make`. Then, I replaced `/usr/bin/make/ with `/usr/local/bin/make` and it looks like it works.